# Implicit conversion from int product to long?

Tags: java, android, implicit-conversion, multiplication

If the product of 2 `int` values does not fit in an `int`, and thus I store it in a `long`, do I need to specify explicit cast to `long` before each operand (or at least before one of the operands)? Or does the compiler correctly handle it even if there is no cast?

This would be the explicit code:

```
public final int baseDistance = (GameCenter.BLOCKSIZE * 3/2);

long baseDistanceSquare = (long)baseDistance * (long)baseDistance;
```

Or is the below code sufficient?

```
long baseDistanceSquare = baseDistance * baseDistance;
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain your downvote? Or stackoverflow is not allowed to be visited by beginners anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side note, this is equivalent to the problem of converting to float the result of an operation with integers; for example:

```
    float f = 2/3;
    System.out.println(f);  // Print 0.0

    f = (float)(2/3);
    System.out.println(f);  // Print 0.0

    f = (float)2/3;
    System.out.println(f);  // Print 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Scratch that. I read it wrong. You do have to cast it to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 1):

correct code is:

```
long baseDistanceSquare = (long)baseDistance * (long)baseDistance;
```

cast value end run a mathematic function

other example:

```
int X;
long Y, Z;
Z = X * Y; // Result is int value
Z = (long) X * Y   //Result is long value
Z = X * 1L //Result is long value
```